# Find OLS solution using optim

Tags: r, optimization, linearmodels

I am trying to find the solution of a linear model using optim. I could use `lm` or even use matrix multiplication to find explicit solution. However, the end goal is to use different objective functions. Since I can't replicate the `lm` solution, there is something wrong with my code and I cannot figure it out. My linear model does not have an intercept term.

Here is an example

```
RSS_f <- function(x){
  f_hat=as.matrix(dat[,2:ncol(dat)])%*%(as.matrix(x))
  error=dat[,1] - f_hat
  return(sum(error^2))
}

x0=rep(0,6)

r<- optim(x0,RSS_f)
```

Here is the sample data I have been using

```
dat=structure(list(y = c(-0.015592301115793, -0.257703905025368, 
0.132944891819098, 0.144585602249198, -0.0834638586276937, -0.132506252754974, 
-0.0671452738850035, 0.017093324992248), x1 = c(0.0762815118005244, 
0.0684222303897641, 0.0126545677701762, -0.0283951453807663, 
0.0682085328963522, 0.030322515917991, -0.0288021662870674, 0.0213481986485853
), x2 = c(0.121096462766523, 0.173507656658378, 0.0830579904733009, 
-0.0131531465094037, 0.14514027572694, -0.00235172620017821, 
-0.116782685211159, 0.128253294500769), x3 = c(0.00271738492481077, 
0.199849189671841, -0.149623094678353, -0.0375499460631867, 0.035188928292329, 
0.0421848373709954, -0.212940391685557, -0.280765720194465), 
    x4 = c(-0.661111149054194, -1.62711136938006, -0.16384009438204, 
    1.24217835189415, -1.01181978837279, -0.968527314213574, 
    -0.271489340669151, -0.602168687364268), x5 = c(1.6840335520254, 
    0.0085051611667053, 0.803743907332177, -1.86248825400901, 
    1.67581124074128, -0.0919360291035565, -0.210122962144954, 
    1.96152949931911), x6 = c(0.251747455313378, -0.353511278663921, 
    -0.155085549001921, -0.376159415130184, -0.0614334625077317, 
    0.759475827597367, 0.10074325959879, 0.512321974431873)), row.names = 63:56, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It would help to show the estimates you get with your method and with `lm` so that readers can know what the problem is without running a bunch of code themselves ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one obvious problem here, and encountered several **non-obvious** problems as I moved forward.

1. you forgot to include an intercept in your model matrix (your edit makes clear that this is not the problem — it would have saved time to mention this in the first place!)
2. when fitting this model with the default (Nelder-Mead) algorithm from these starting points, it takes more than the default number of iterations (500) to converge.
3. your example set of data/predictors is close to multicollinear, which makes naive/"brute force" optimization approaches unstable

Slightly reorganized objective function (the only important difference is `cbind(1, ...)` to add an intercept column to the model matrix: point (1) above)

```r
RSS_f <- function(beta, dat){
    ## inefficient, should compute these outside the loop, but ...
    X <- cbind(1, as.matrix(dat[,-1]))
    y <- dat[,1]
    f_ha <- X %*% beta
    return(sum((y - f_ha)^2))
}
```

```r
x0 <- rep(0,7)  ## need one additional element in the vector for the intercept
r <- optim(x0, RSS_f, dat=dat, control = list(maxit = 1e5))
```

Points 2 and 3 are related to @ZheyuanLi's answer (i.e., picking a good starting point will mitigate them).

Point (2): if we run this `optim()` *without* the `control(list(maxit = 1e5))`, it fails to converge — but **silently**. You have to look at `r$convergence`, see that the value is 1 and not 0 (zero = "converged"), and then go look at `?optim` to see that `r$convergence == 1` means "maximum number of iterations observed".

Point (3): if you look at the coefficients, you'll see that they still don't quite match `lm`. This data set has 8 observations and 7 predictors, which makes the OLS fit pretty ambitious (although not impossible). I tried a few other options (e.g. `method = "BFGS"` in `optim()`), which didn't help much.

You can get an idea of the stability of the OLS problem by looking at the ratio of the largest to the smallest eigenvalue of `crossprod(X)` (i.e., `t(X) %*% X`); in this case it's a factor of about 1e5 (bad news).

```r
X <- cbind(1, as.matrix(dat[,-1]))
eigen(crossprod(X))$values
[1] 2.034880e+01 6.082053e+00 2.730513e+00 9.748323e-01 8.148341e-02
[6] 1.358231e-02 9.186567e-05
```

Alternatively, compute the *condition number*: `Matrix::condest(crossprod(X))` is 2.75e5 (again, a large value is bad).

For comparison, if I generate predictors randomly (`m <- matrix(rnorm(48), nrow = 8)`), add an intercept column, and compute the condition number of `crossprod(m)`, the values are typically on the order of 500 (1000 random replicates ranged from about 20 to 30,000). So part of the problem is 'not much data for a model with this many predictors', but your example is even worse than a randomly sampled one.

R's built-in method for fitting linear models (QR with a custom pivoting strategy) works robustly even on such ill-posed problems.

I don't think removing the intercept will change the ill-conditioning problem very much, although I haven't checked.

Answer (score 3):

**You forget the intercept.** `lm` fits a model

*y = a + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 + b4 * x4 + b5 * x5 + b6 * x6 + error*

while you are trying

*y = b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 + b4 * x4 + b5 * x5 + b6 * x6 + error*

Redefine your function as:

```
RSS_f <- function(x, dat) {
  f_hat <- x[1] + as.matrix(dat[, -1]) %*% x[-1]
  error <- dat[, 1] - f_hat
  sum(error^2)
}
```

**You also need to choose initial value for `optim` wisely.**

```
b <- unname(lm(y ~ ., data = dat)$coefficients)
#[1]  0.07462097 -2.48751498  0.37746968  0.40302696  0.18224149  0.09565363
#[7]  0.02259334

## in a neighborhood of true values
init <- rnorm(length(b), mean = b, sd = 0.01)

r <- optim(init, RSS_f, dat = dat)
r$par
#[1]  0.07248056 -2.39952127  0.37383708  0.38479202  0.18192510  0.09347675
#[7]  0.02204713
```

---

**I was slow in finishing my answer...**

As Prof. Bolker mentions, `optim` struggles to converge so we see discrepancy in the computed results (`r$converge` is 1, not 0), even if `init` is close to `b` enough. I was about to say that you have too few data: 8 data vs 7 parameters or 6 parameters (no intercept) is just hard for approximation-based numerical optimization.

While Bolker suggests that you can tune `optim` by increasing `maxit`, the default simplex method (i.e., Nelder-Mead) is just too slow. What I often suggest, is to use `method = "BFGS"` and provide exact gradient via argument `gr` whenever we can. This will dramatically increase accuracy, convergence rate and computation speed.

```
RSS_g <- function (x, dat) {
  y <- dat[, 1]
  X <- cbind(1, as.matrix(dat[, -1]))
  y_hat <- X %*% x
  error <- y - y_hat
  -2 * crossprod(X, error)
}

optim(init, fn = RSS_f, gr = RSS_g, method = "BFGS", dat = dat)
#$par
#[1]  0.07469957 -2.49096695  0.37763926  0.40371461  0.18224659  0.09573302
#[7]  0.02261385
#
#$value
#[1] 0.008676038
#
#$counts
#function gradient 
#      24       16   ## 16 steps till convergence
#
#$convergence
#[1] 0
#
#$message
#NULL
```

For the poor initial value `numeric(7)`. It takes more steps to converge, but `maxit = 400` is sufficient.

```
optim(numeric(7), fn = RSS_f, gr = RSS_g, method = "BFGS", dat = dat,
      control = list(maxit = 400))
#$par
#[1]  0.07113841 -2.33775916  0.36920607  0.37293500  0.18186110  0.09220104
#[7]  0.02139395
#
#$value
#[1] 0.008678216
#
#$counts
#function gradient   ## 349 steps till convergence
#     477      349 
#
#$convergence
#[1] 0
#
#$message
#NULL
```

---

**Full Newton's method**

Even better is to provide exact Hessian matrix and use `nlm` instead of `optim`.

```
RSS_h <- function (x, dat) {
  X <- cbind(1, as.matrix(dat[, -1]))
  2 * crossprod(X)
}

attr(RSS_f, "gradient") <- RSS_g
attr(RSS_f, "hessian") <- RSS_h

nlm(RSS_f, numeric(7), dat = dat)
$minimum
[1] 0.008676037

$estimate
[1]  0.07462042 -2.48751019  0.37747413  0.40302288  0.18224109  0.09565303
[7]  0.02259344

$gradient
[1] -8.815716e-08 -3.457165e-08  6.583843e-08 -8.195144e-08 -3.034804e-07
[6] -7.572794e-07 -1.521478e-07

$code  ## 1 or 2 means convergence
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 44
```

Optimization is an art. There is a lot to consider. But generally speaking, the more useful information you provide, the easier for computers to do the dirty work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question, my model does not have intercept term, so my function was done correctly. It is just strange that the solution is not the same, there should be convergence for such a simple quadradic formula.

Comment: See my answer for some mathematical/computational answers of why this problem is hard.